# get a list of files from a public dropbox folder using jquery client side

Tags: jquery, cors, dropbox, screen-scraping

I have a list of files in a public dropbox folder. I want to get a list of these files and their public urls on my web page using jquery running on the client. Dropbox have various api's for server side technologies but I want to do this using client side javascript. Even trying to access the html page with a view to scraping the list - results in issues with the cross origin request. Anyone know of any good tutorial to point me in the write direction.

Comment: What browsers are you using?

Comment: chrome and firefox

Comment: Add this flag `-disable-web-security -user-data-dir` in chrome startup.